# What's the difference between app restart from Xcode and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a problem in my iPad application after terminating.
I loaded my application to device throw Xcode, and finished it execution.
When I restart this application from Xcode (click Run button), everything is OK.
But if i try to run application from mobile device (click on application ico), i have bad result (some data files become inconsistent).

If i save all files from application to Mac after application terminating, and then try to start application by this two ways in the same datafiles...this problem appears too...

What the different between this two ways to run application (from Xcode and from device)?
What different functions are called in first and second cases?
Thanks for your help...

Comment: which kind of data files become inconsistent ?

Comment: it is the database file, that i encrypt after terminating and decrypt on app start

Comment: How are you 'finishing' the execution on your app?

Comment: double-click on home button and put the red minus...

Comment: I think you should post the code that loads and the code that saves your data

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in how they are launched, or.... maybe. You see, the thing is that an app in iOS doesn't really get terminated by the user.

When you start the app from XCode, it kills any running instance and restarts it.

When you start the app from the device, it just opens the app in the state if was left the last time you used it (unless it was killed for memory or resource reasons)

Comment: The app can also be explicitly killed by the user on the device. If you double-click the home button, it allows you to kill apps from there.

Comment: In addition to @Gavin's comment there *is* a little difference. When you start it in Xcode it gets attached to the debugger ;)

Comment: @HAS Yes, but there's no indication that the debugger is causing his data to become corrupted.

Comment: @Gavin I know, I just wanted to say that the first sentence is not entirely true in general ;)

Comment: Yes such as in @Gavin comment i go to terminate my app throw double-click on home button...

Comment: But the different is taking place when i  upload identical data throw Xcode organizer to device

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!

The problem was in lifecycle of iOs application.
iOS system interrupts app startup if it takes more than 5-10 seconds ( source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html )

But! If we run throw XCode this interruption does't appear...

There may be two solution
1. Using dispatch_async for hard tasks in startup (doesn't useful for me, because startup tasks MUST have been performed first )
2. Start all hard tasks after startup (may be after button clicked or in controller load)- i have used this solution and everything become good!

Answer (score -1):

If you kill the app using Xcode while the app is in the foreground, you could end up with stuff that's inconsistent and not yet saved. But if you background the app first and wait a short time (like 10 seconds) and then you kill the app from Xcode, it should be basically the same as backgrounding and then killing the app on the device. Some things in your app are probably getting saved/synchronized at the time you background the app, which won't happen if you kill it from Xcode while the app is in the foreground.

EDIT:

Make sure that when you write your data files that you're doing it atomically as well. This will prevent the files from being only partially written, because it will first write it to a temp file and then move it into place once it's done writing it. If your app were getting killed midway thru this writing, that could corrupt the files if they're not being written atomically.